# flot - show time axis without gaps

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, flot

I'm trying to customize jQuery Flot to remove gaps between dots on time axis. Look at the top image:

[image: broken flot]

It shows the data for two days, and I bet you spot the night. What I want to do is to get rid of this annoying gap in the middle of the chart. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: This is interesting:  http://groups.google.com/group/flot-graphs/browse_thread/thread/35780408406a2bc6/54361b26fbe8e83e?lnk=gst&q=next#54361b26fbe8e83e

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Too bad I can't accept a comment as an answer, since the answer from George Roberts from Mark's link worked smoothly.

So what I had to do is to change the mode of the flot from 'time' to null and then emulate a time axis.

I've created two arrays: the first one with data for the graph and the second one with timestamps:

```
for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++ ) {
    dotsData.push( [i, json[i].value] );
    ticks.push( json[i].date );
    }                       
}
```

Time axis emulation:

```
// flot options
... xaxis: { tickFormatter: function(val) { return formTicks(val, ticks) } } ...

// formTicks function
function formTicks(val, ticksArr) {
    var tick = ticksArr[val];

    if ( tick != undefined ) {
        tick = new Date( tick );

        var hours = tick.getHours(),
            minutes = tick.getMinutes();

            tick = hours+':'+minutes;
    }
    else { tick = '' }

    return tick
}
```

It solves the problem, but it's hard to distinguish one day from another, so I added markings:

```
var markings = [],
    firstDay = new Date( ticks[0] ).getDate();

    for (var i=1; i<ticks.length; i++) {
        var loopDay = new Date( ticks[i] ).getDate();
        if ( loopDay != firstDay ) {
            var marking = {
                color: '#000000',
                lineWidth: 1,
                xaxis: { from: i, to: i }
            }

        markings.push( marking )

        firstDay = loopDay; // loop through all days
    }
}

// flot options
grid: { markings: markings }
```

The result:

[image: Fine looking flot]

Comment: thanks for coming back and posting your full solution.  When SO lets you accept your own answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use transform and `inverseTransform`, which were designed for situations such as this. See the following portion of the FLOT documentation.

> "transform" and "inverseTransform" are callbacks you can put in to
>   change the way the data is drawn. You can design a function to
>   compress or expand certain parts of the axis non-linearly, e.g.
>   suppress weekends or compress far away points with a logarithm or some
>   other means. When Flot draws the plot, each value is first put through
>   the transform function. Here's an example, the x axis can be turned
>   into a natural logarithm axis with the following code:

```
xaxis: {
        transform: function (v) { return Math.log(v); },
        inverseTransform: function (v) { return Math.exp(v); }
       }
```

Comment: I've already tried this. I used `function (v) { if ($.inArray(v, timestamps) > -1){return v} else {return null} }`. It removes ticks in the gap, but the gap is still there.

Comment: Daniel, could you post your code, so I can see the FLOT call and the data being plotted?

Comment: Daniel, I just did my own experiment using xaxis: transform amd I'm afraid I have to agree with you.  It doesn't seem to do what it is supposed to do. Sorry I can't help!!! Regards

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway, Neil.