# Graphing time series data w/flot and ignoring large block of times

Tags: jquery, graph, time-series, data-visualization, flot

I'm graphing stock data with Flot. If I graph a single day it works fine. If I graph 2 or more days in the same graph, there is a long line between the end of the first day and the start of the second day.

Correctly, Flot sees no data (the markets closed) and thus just draws a line to the start of the new day.

How can I get Flot to ignore the time between market close (4PM EST) and market open (9:30AM EST)?

Image attached: [image: Flot graph]

My plotting data is:

```
$(function () {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"),
[ { data: [[1355131782000000, "2.95"], [1355132082000000, "2.99"], [1355132382000000, "2.97"], [1355132682000000, "2.9699"], [1355132982000000, "2.955"], [1355133282000000, "2.92"], [1355133582000000, "2.91"], [1355133882000000, "2.95"], [1355134182000000, "2.94"], [1355134482000000, "2.935"], [1355134782000000, "2.92"], [1355135082000000, "2.92"], [1355135382000000, "2.91"], [1355135682000000, "2.9"], [1355135982000000, "2.8901"], [1355136282000000, "2.865"], [1355136582000000, "2.92"], [1355136882000000, "2.945"], [1355137182000000, "2.95"], [1355137482000000, "2.925"], [1355137782000000, "2.92"], [1355138082000000, "2.925"], [1355138382000000, "2.92"], [1355138682000000, "2.92"], [1355138982000000, "2.93"], [1355139282000000, "2.9201"], [1355139582000000, "2.93"], [1355139882000000, "2.925"], [1355140182000000, "2.9115"], [1355140482000000, "2.92"], [1355140782000000, "2.91"], [1355141082000000, "2.92"], [1355141382000000, "2.91"], [1355141682000000, "2.91"], [1355141982000000, "2.915"], [1355142282000000, "2.915"], [1355142582000000, "2.91"], [1355142882000000, "2.905"], [1355143182000000, "2.9"], [1355143482000000, "2.9"], [1355143782000000, "2.89"], [1355144382000000, "2.885"], [1355144682000000, "2.88"], [1355144982000000, "2.89"], [1355145282000000, "2.89"], [1355145582000000, "2.89"], [1355145882000000, "2.89"], [1355146182000000, "2.88"], [1355146482000000, "2.885"], [1355146782000000, "2.89"], [1355147082000000, "2.89"], [1355147382000000, "2.88"], [1355147682000000, "2.88"], [1355147982000000, "2.89"], [1355148282000000, "2.89"], [1355148582000000, "2.88"], [1355148882000000, "2.88"], [1355149182000000, "2.9"], [1355149482000000, "2.9"], [1355149782000000, "2.89"], [1355150382000000, "2.9"], [1355150682000000, "2.91"], [1355150982000000, "2.9"], [1355151282000000, "2.91"], [1355151582000000, "2.9001"], [1355151882000000, "2.905"], [1355152182000000, "2.9015"], [1355152482000000, "2.9"], [1355152782000000, "2.96"], [1355153082000000, "3.0"], [1355153382000000, "3.01"], [1355153682000000, "3.005"], [1355153982000000, "3.005"], [1355154282000000, "3.01"], [1355154582000000, "3.01"], [1355154882000000, "3.02"], [1355155182000000, "3.02"]] } ],
{ xaxes: [ { mode: 'time', 
             twelveHourClock: true,
             timeformat: "%H:%M%p"} ],
  yaxes: [  ] })
});
```

**UPDATED** (per answer) with new graph:
[image]

This is not what I want. I want to basically collapse the graph between the market close and open. I don't want to see the large gap ...

Comment: I had the same problem. I think this answer will solve your problem too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204232/flot-show-time-axis-without-gaps

Answer (score 3):

Add fake data points with x-axis values falling within the gaps and y-axis values of null to create a discontinuity.

See the [Data Format](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format) section of the API docs for more information.

Edit: to actually collapse the axis to show only the available data, don't use time-mode. If values aren't increasing monotonically, then you aren't really showing time, and should instead specify an array of x-axis ticks manually based on the data that's available.

Comment: well, this doesn't work as expected - I've updated my OP with a picture of the new result. I've added two timestamps with null values between the closing and opening times. See new graph ...

Comment: OK, I was thinking that - I also tried to graph them as two sets of data, but that just changed the color, heh. I'll try your suggestion, that should work.