# How to remove a gap in time mode series of Flot js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datetime, flot

How to remove gap in time mode series ?

my xaxis option is :

```
xaxis: {
  mode: "time",
  tick: ['1380585600000','1380672000000','1380758400000','1380844800000','1381104000000'],
  timeformat: "%e-%b-%y",
  tickSize: [1,"day"],
  tickLength: 0,
  autoscaleMargin:0
}
```

[image]

Comment: provide it in jsfiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [flot - show time axis without gaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204232/flot-show-time-axis-without-gaps)

Answer (score 2):

In `time` mode all ticks on the xaxis have the same distant to each other (here one day) regardless whether you have datapoints for the day or not.

The only way to get ticks with different time-distances is to use `categories` mode.